# Ошибка при работе с Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, webview, logcat

Пишу простое приложение-браузер. При первой загрузке приложения, должна загружаться страница с url'ом "https://navsegda.net". В итоге страница так и не прогружается, а в логах Android Studio получаю вот это:

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(157)] "invalid params passed into zE.identify [object Object]", source: https://static.zdassets.com/web_widget/latest/vendors~web_widget.9f98c9497afde8f897db.chunk.js (157)
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-messaging.js (1)
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://m.navsegda.net/') with script ('https://m.navsegda.net/service-worker-v1.0.1.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed", source: https://m.navsegda.net/ (0)

Как думаете, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что браузер не поддерживает АПИ для работы с firebase.

Comment: Я с firebase ещё не работал. Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Я просто перевел текст ошибки.